# int[] to byte[], am i forgetting something?

Tags: c#

This is untested as i need to write more code. But is this correct and i feel like i am missing something, like this could be better written. Do i need the c.lose at the end? should i flush anything(i'll assume no if i do close())?

```
Byte[] buffer;
using (var m = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var binWriter = new BinaryWriter(m))
    {
        foreach (var v in wordIDs)
            binWriter.Write(v);
        binWriter.Close();
    }
    buffer = m.GetBuffer();
    m.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the .Close() calls (the automatic .Dispose() the using block generates takes care of those).

Also, you'll want to use .ToArray() on the MemoryStream, not .GetBuffer(). GetBuffer() returns the underlying buffer, no matter how much of it is used.  ToArray() returns a copy that is the perfect length.

If you're using this to communicate with another program, make sure you and it agree on the order of the bytes (aka endianness).  If you're using network byte-order, you'll need to flip the order of the bytes (using something like IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder()), as network byte-order is big-endian, and BinaryWriter uses little-endian.

Answer (score 2):

What is wordIDs, is it an enumeration or is it an Int32[]? You can use the following if it is just Int32[]:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[wordIDs.Length * 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(wordIDs, 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Otherwise, if wordIDs is an enumeration that you must step through, all you need to change is remove the m.Close (as mentioned) and use MemoryStream.ToArray (as mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Close is not needed here.  The using statements will ensure the Dispose method on these types are called on exit and this will have the same effect as calling Close.  In fact if you look at the code in reflector, you'll find that Close in both cases just proxies off to the Dispose method on both types.

Answer (score 0):

Thus sayeth [Skeet](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/265767-memorystream-binarywriter-buffering-question):

> There's no real *need* to close either
>   a MemoryStream or a BinaryWriter, but
>   I think it's good form to use a using
>   statement to dispose of both - that
>   way if you change at a later date to
>   use something that really *does* need
>   disposing, it will fit into the same
>   code.

So you don't need the Close or the using statement, but using is idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 0):

JaredPar's and Jonathan's answers are correct. If you want an alternative, you use `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)`. So now your code turns into this

```
wordIDs.SelectMany(i => BitConverter.GetBytes(i));
```

Comment: Or, you could use BitConverter.GetBytes(int), plus IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder() if you need to flip the bytes as well.

Comment: @Jonathan: I knew there had to be a function to do it, I just couldn't remember its name.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the Skeet here.

Whilst you may not *need* close by using using you are relying on the implementation of BinaryWriter and MemoryStream to do it for you in the Dispose method. This is true for framework types, but what if someone writes a Writer or Stream which doesn't do it?

Adding close does no harm and protects you against badly written classes.

Comment: You don't need to protect yourself from bad classes that don't exist yet, what are saying is called bad coding, because it adds noise for no good reasons. "What if someone doesn't do something the right way" is not a good excuse to pollute your code with redundant statements.

Comment: Except it doesn't really add noise at all, it's more expressive and specific. Defensive programming is not pollution.

Comment: A Dispose() should _always_ close a resource-based class that implements IDisposable. If it doesn't, then it's not implemented correctly.